# Removing subsection numbers in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using the `report` style.

I'm using `\subsection*` to suppress the numbers that would otherwise appear before my subsection text.

I'm generating a table of contents using `setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`

But the subsection numbers are appearing in the generated table of contents.

Is there a way to suppress the numbers for the subsections in the table of contents, like you can suppress them using `\subsection*` rather than `\subsection?`

(I want the chapter and section numbers to appear for new chapters and sections, as they currently are).

Comment: What happens with `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}`? Or do you want the `subsection`'s name on `toc` but not numbered there but numbered on the text?

Comment: The TOC doesn't display the subsection title either.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\subsection*` everywhere; just say `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` before `\begin{document}` and use `\subsection` normally. If you want the subsections in the TOC, add also `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use `\subsection*` everywhere, if you never want subsections to be numbered. Instead, add

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1} % levels under \section are not numbered
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    % levels under \subsection are not listed in the TOC
```

Example with `article`, but with `report` or `book` (or most of the other classes)

```
\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1} % levels under \section are not numbered
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}    % levels under \subsection are not listed in the TOC

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Some title}
Here's the text.

\subsection{Again}
And again.

\section{Conclusion}
Enough.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
\subsection*{text here}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{text here}
```

And set the depth of the table of contents to be above the subsection level, using `\setcounter{tocdepth}{appropriate value here}`

Unfortunately though, you need to write "text here" in two places.